# iOS: Getting memory warning while manipulating video each frames and re writing with audio files

Tags: ios, swift

I need to export video while manipulating it's each frame with a background image. Now i am assembling it again with final frames and on writing it using `AVAssetWriter` getting memory warning with 50 frames.

I am using swift-video-generator and sending all frames and single audio file for generating final output.

```
    private  func getVideoAllFramesAndAppendItWithFinalCanvasImageBackground(asset:AVAsset, backgroundImage:UIImage, videoRect:CGRect) {
        var frameCount:Int = 0
        let lastIndex:Int = 130 //Checking optimize way to handle all frame without reading it in memory
        let assetReader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
        let assetReaderOutputSettings = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
        ]
        let assetReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: assetTrack, outputSettings: assetReaderOutputSettings)
        assetReaderOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
        assetReader.add(assetReaderOutput)
        assetReader.startReading()

        var sample: CMSampleBuffer? = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
        while (sample != nil) {
            frameCount = frameCount + 1
            print(frameCount)
            sample = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
            if sample != nil {
                self.convertBufferImageToUIImage(sampleBuffer: sample!, canvasExportImage: backgroundImage, videoRect: videoRect)

            }
            if frameCount == lastIndex {
                break
            }
        }
        print(frameCount)
        if lastIndex == frameCount {
           self.writeVideoWithFinalFrames(finalFrames: self.finalVideoExportFrames, videoAsset:asset)
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to do that without facing memory issue in iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
while (assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() != nil) {
            autoreleasepool {
                frameCount = frameCount + 1
                print(frameCount)
                let sample: CMSampleBuffer? = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
                if sample != nil {
                    self.convertBufferImageToUIImage(sampleBuffer: sample!, canvasExportImage: backgroundImage, videoRect: videoRect)

                }
                if frameCount == lastIndex {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Thanks Mike, It reduces the memory after processing all frames. can you help me to do it one bye one modified frame rather than all keeping in memory ?